# Using generics with static methods

Tags: typescript

To represent data from an HTTP Api and convert it into an internal version, I want to type classes with generic.

Here's the example closest example I can write :

```js
abstract class From<T> {
    // Invalid typescript is here
    abstract static from<T>(value: T): ThisType<From<T>>;
}

class AnimalApi implements From<Animal> {
    constructor (public name: string) {}

    public static from(value: Animal): AnimalApi {
        return new AnimalApi(value.name);
    }
} 

class Animal implements From<AnimalApi> {
    constructor (public name: string) {}

    public static from(value: AnimalApi): Animal {
        return new Animal(value.name);
    }
} 

class ExportApi<ApiT extends From<InternalT>, InternalT extends From<ApiT>> {
    constructor (public data: ApiT) {}
}

class Export<InternalT extends From<ApiT>, ApiT extends From<InternalT>> {
    constructor (public data: InternalT) {}
}

const animalExportApi = new ExportApi(new AnimalApi("Wo"));
const animalExport = new Export(Animal.from(animalExportApi.data));
console.log(animalExport)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYlA9gWwB4AVAPgQG8AoBGhAejoQEkA7AN2GQEsATBCAJ4AHAKZhYULkMRcMACxFQR1WqEgx4CSMAhdYCAGa5CpABQdkAVxEAuBEQCUdonNlFhIgtnzESJANyUAL6UlChoGACCLFx4nJFCXAixQsgieCIsEBjehNGxnGRUtEg4LOqW8DhQCKZCliDc+izAGXbqXCwA5g4UISo09Y16WhA6I0b45pzWdvlxyE4I8-GJFAMlCEoQllAsCCwiAO7LMQsJXNNWIgB0LRkOgSUhQQih4einBcjJeKnpmWyWGMBBWyAuRQ2sDKFSqNTqDSaB1atlGkm6vXI-RKQyR2l0+kmeCusy+50SSzB602tG2u32hxOYJJt3uIkeGxebzCqE+AFEAB5CaoQC6gxJEBAiAUQTI8HIg1iyvacUgAGmYWUULWQkulspY8uBPgupEhJWh5WglQg1VquJGPB0wDmEsxL3evIwguFUAgBCV2tVUplcoVJolJA1ppDBqNuQDWpVur81NolthtvhDv0TrGdkDyccfWC7xhiGAZ04PpFFwQAF4DscEDW-RdTIyyatLgAiADqOB7Dg5GYrVeQrcQjc7k9MYJuRNMle+k4uNzzwGHgQzODSN2QOC6S-Hk4clCAA)

There are multiple problems here :

- 'static' modifier cannot be used with 'abstract' modifier
- Static members cannot reference class type parameters
- A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface
- Parameter 'value' of public static method from exported class has or is using private name 'T'

I can't replace `abstract class From<T>` by an interface, because [TypeScript don't allow static methods in interfaces](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13462).

**Question is**: How to implement `From<T>` in TypeScript ?

*NB: There is the From trait in Rust for inspiration : https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html*

Comment: If `From` is an abstract class, you don't use `implements` (`class Animal implements From<AnimalApi>`), you use **`extends`** (`class Animal extends From<AnimalApi>`). Also note that an abstract class can't make subclasses implement `static` methods (they inherit `static` methods from the superclass).

Comment: I fixed the playground to match with the question. The definition of `from` method here is not very important. As I search how to implement `From` pattern. Ok, I understand about extends/implements. So, it seems not possible to use abstract class or interface with static method. Do you have an idea about how implements the `From` pattern in TypeScript ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I won't be surprised to discover that you can't do that in TypeScript.

Comment: What are you trying to express with `ThisType<From<T>>`? Does From have any instance properties or methods that depend on `T`? If so, you could you provide a minimal reproducible example that shows it? Otherwise `From<T>` the type is just `{}` and [weird things happen](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).